# C#,,InvokeMember("click")

Tags: c#, invokemember

I'm working on a WinForms project and am running lines 1 to 7 normally. After the seventh line exits to the for loop (like break;), SendMail() doesn't work. Why?

```
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{
    if (mesajlistem[k].InnerText == "test")
    {
        if (saatler[k] != saatlistem[k].InnerText)
        {
            link[k].InvokeMember("click");
            SendMail(document.GetElementById("divItmPrts").InnerHtml); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? What does `document.GetElementById("divItmPrts").InnerHtml` contain? What do you expect to happen? The seventh line doesn't do anything to exit the `for` loop. Can you add more detail?

Comment: http://i.cubeupload.com/qazE3r.png please see this pic.
Actually I need programmaticly send latest 3 mails content.

Answer (score 0):

So its seems that mail gets sent but it is empty

So either

```
documet.GetElement...
```

is not return the right thing. Or

```
Sendmail(xx)
```

is not correct

So set a breakpoint at the start of SendMail and see if good data is being passed in.

Now fix the broken part

(Not an answer I know, but too long for a comment)